# Putting images on the navbar in rails only displays theimage name and not the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

The image I have been trying to put as a logo on the navbar only displays the name. I have the image in the asset pipeline in a folder called images and I am using bootstrap. I currently have this in my code:

```
`<%= link_to image_tag('WikiLogoFinal.jpg'), getting_started_path, id: "logo" %>`
```

my CSS as follows:

```
#logo {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
font-size: 1.7em;
color: $niceBlandGreen;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: -1px;
padding-top: 9px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1;
&:hover {
font-size: 1.75em;
color: white;
background: $shinyOrange;
text-decoration: none;
}
}
```

the image is not the problem as I have used a different one.

Comment: are those back tics in your actual code?

Comment: No those are this websites' formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have, your code should work. Make sure that you have your image in the

```
app/assets/images
```

directory. Also, check to make sure that you have the asset pipeline enabled. Go to

```
config/application.rb
```

and see if you have this line:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add logo or image into your navbar. Perform following steps to do so:

1. Open your navbar.html.erb, generally this files lies under the layout folder in views and then look for navbar-brand class for e.g.,

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="img-responsive2" src ="https://www.google.com.mx/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"> BLOG</a>
```

2. Add following code into your navbar.scss file under the class .navbar

   ```
   .img-responsive2 {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 20%;
   height: auto;}
   ```

I hope by following above steps you can add image or logo into your navbar